# Script for executing command for a list of files

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to execute a command for a list of files that convert them from one format to another, say:

```
conv -option MYOPTION file1 > file1.output
```

However, I have a list of files in a folder, say:

> file1, file2, …, fileN

I need a script that runs such command for each and every file, something like:

> script.sh MYOPTION *.TXT

I did some research and found something like:

```
for f in *; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Now the problems are:

1. How do I get the "list of files", in my example, `*.TXT`, into the script so it's mapped to the list of files? (ie. no hardcoded `*` in the script, it should work also if I only specify one single file)
2. How do I invoke system command in a script? Something like `conv -option $1`?

Thanks!

Comment: `conv -option "$f"`. Why do you think it would be different from the way you invoke `echo`?

Comment: Oh thanks! So I can put the command call just like `echo` inside a script? I didn't realise it's not a script keyword.

Comment: A script is just shell commands put into a file and executed automatically.